# Initializing population for real numbers in genetic algorithm

Tags: matrix, vector, julia, genetic-algorithm

```
npop = 100
R_max = [5,14]
R_min = [0,7]
intpop = zeros(npop,2)
function initpopReal(npop, R_max, R_min)
    for i = 1:npop
        intpop[i,1] = rand(0:5)
        intpop[i,2] = rand(7:14)
    end
    intpop
end
```

I'm trying to initialize my population for real numbers genetic algorithm.
npop is my population size.
I created a matrix with npop rows and 2 columns.
I want to fill this matrix with random numbers between (0,5) in the first column and between (7,14) in the second column.
The problem is, whenever I run this function I get the matrix filled with zeros 
Do I have any syntax or logical errors?

Answer (score 2):

You do not ever call the `initpopReal` function.

Comment: Also, you should prefer to pass initpop as a parameter to the function, rather than refer to a global variable.